# Does Azure has a TTS (text to speech) service that allows more than 1024 chars?

Tags: azure, text-to-speech

Unfortunately Bing TTS Service allow a 1024 max characters to each request.

Does Azure has another a TTS (text to speech) service that allows more than 1024 chars?

Answer (score 0):

Azure cognitive services supports text to speech of large text. The two main methods are to use the REST text to speech API which has a limit of 64kb of SSML text per request. The other method is to use the Audio Content Creation tool that supports 3,000 characters with the free tier, and 20,000 characters with the Standard S0 tier (paid). This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-services-quotas-and-limits